# How To List All The Attributes Within A Tag Using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

Let's say I have an HTML file with this in it:

```css
<div class="parentclass">
  <img alt="puppydog" class="" src="https://google.com/puppydawgimage.png" title="puppy dog" />
</div>
```

my Python Script looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

html = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") 

stuff = html.find_all("div", class_="parentclass") 

parentclassstuff = [] 

for x in stuff: 
    #This adds all of the tags specific to the criteria of "div" and "parentclass". 
    parentclassstuff.append(x) 

print(parentclassstuff[0]) 
'''This outputs: 
<div class="parentclass">
<img alt="puppydog" class="" src="https://google.com/puppydawgimage.png" title="puppy dog"/></div>'''
```

What I want to do is access the individual attributes of parentclassstuff[0] like this:

```
parentclassstuff[0]["img alt"] = "puppydog" 

parentclassstuff[0]["src"] = "https://google.com/puppydawgimage.png"
```

etc...

However I can't find a way to do that. I have tried the parentclassstuff[0].get(attribute) method among others. The output of parentclassstuff[0] is not a string but a "class 'bs4.element.Tag'". Worse case scenario I could just convert it to a string and slice the data I need but I would think Beautiful Soup would provide an easy way to access this data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The variable "stuff" in my example is a list of all of the sub-classes of the "parentclass" class. This involved me accessing the sub-classes as such (note: I technically did not need the "x in stuff" loop in my example because the variable "stuff" pretty much acts like a list itself albeit is not technically a "list" type):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

html = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") 

stuff = html.find_all("div", class_="parentclass") 

#An empty list put my attributes in (the attributes will be in a dict format). 
attributes = {}
#
for x in range(0, len(stuff)): 
     #This accesses the subclass by class name: 
     subclass = stuff[x].find(class__ = "") 
     attribute = subclass.attr 
     attributes.append(attribute) 

#The output will be: 

attributes = [{"img alt": "puppydog", "class": "", "src": "https://google.com/puppydawgimage.png", "title": "puppy dog"}] 

#If there is more than one subclass tag then the above list will add it in order accordingly.
```